# my two python functions are overriding each other?

Tags: python, regex, function, if-statement, overriding

```
import re
score = 0

capital_letters = r'[A-Z]'
a = re.compile(capital_letters)

lowercase_letters = r'[a-z]'
b = re.compile(lowercase_letters)

def increase_score (aValue, aScore):
  aScore += aValue
  return aScore

def upper_score(test_string, aScore):
  if re.match(a, test_string):
    aScore = increase_score(5, aScore)
    print (aScore)
    print("UPPERCASE")
  else:
    print("The password needs capital letters for a higher score")


def lower_score(test_string, aScore):
    if re.match(b, test_string):
      aScore = increase_score(5, aScore)
  print (aScore)
  print("LOWERCASE")
else:
  print("The password needs lowercase letters for a higher score")

password = input("Enter a password to check")
upper_score(password, score)
lower_score(password, score)
```

If I input all upper case letters I get this output:

```
5
UPPERCASE
The password needs lowercase letters for a higher score
```

If I input all lower case letters I get this output:

The password needs capital letters for a higher score
   5
   LOWERCASE

These results I am happy with.

THE PROBLEM IS when I combine uppercase and lowercase letters I get this result:

```
The password needs capital letters for a higher score
5
LOWERCASE
```

1) Even though there are both uppercase and lowercase letters the score is still 5 instead of 10.

2) The regex for uppercase letters stops working even though there are uppercase letters in the string.

Thank you!!! I hope I explained this well.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?  Where is the code that calls these functions?

Comment: You don't seem to have included all the necessary code for us to understand the problem

Comment: increase_score(5, aScore) ????

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrate the error. Please include any input along with the actual and expected output of the program. Please include the full text of any error messages. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Im sorry for the missing code, I have now put any missing code into the question

Comment: hopefully this looks better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.match` looks for the characters at the BEGINNING of the given string. Use `re.search` instead.

See also [search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Comment: thank you this solved my second issue :D

im still having the issue that the total score is 5 and not 10, however :(

Answer (score 1):

### Brief

You don't even need regex for this. Python has [`isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) and [`islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) functions available.

---

### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/tsia7M)

```
passwords = [
    "all lowercase letters",
    "ALL UPPERCASE LETTERS",
    "Mixed lowercase and UPPERCASE letters"
]

def lower_score(string, weight):
    if any(s.islower() for s in string):
        print "Contains: LOWERCASE"
        return weight
    else:
        print "Message: The password needs lowercase letters for a higher score"
    return 0

def upper_score(string, weight):
    if any(s.isupper() for s in string):
        print "Contains: UPPERCASE"
        return weight
    else:
        print "Message: The password needs capital letters for a higher score"
    return 0

for password in passwords:
    print "Password: " + password
    score = 0
    score += lower_score(password, 5)
    score += upper_score(password, 5)
    print "Score: " + str(score) + "\n"
```